# How to prevent WebStorm from prefixing imports with "@root/src"

Tags: webstorm

WebStorm version 2018.3.2

Already played around with these settings

Editor > Code Style > TypeScript

Editor > Code Style > JavaScript

Imports tab - nothing seems to work.

[image]

Comment: please check your `tsconfig.json` - do you have any path mappings defined in it?

Comment: Yes, I had one - I removed it and it's working now.